# Render passes and Lens distortion

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-passes

I'm currently rendering out rendering passes that I'll later combine in Photoshop for some composition work.
One thing I don't understand is how to include my Lens Distortion in the passes. I have it in the combined pass, but how do I connect it so that it also affects the individual rendering passes?

[image]